# fedora 22 - change from gnome to kde4

Tags: fedora

I have installed Fedora 22 workstation, which defaults to the gnome desktop.  I just did a

```
sudo yum groups install kde4
```

Judging by the messages, the install succeeded.  Then, I did a complete power-off and then rebooted.  At no point was I given the option of selecting kde4 rather than gnome; I would now like to make kde4 the default desktop.  Request help.

Comment: Does it give you the option when you login? There should be a gear icon or something at the bottom of the password box. After that it'll just remember that's the last DE you used.

Comment: No option given when I login (click on my name), perhaps because I specified no password with my name.  What about installing some switch application that provides gui for switching desktop (plausibly requiring reboot)?  Alternatively, what about manually editing some config file?

Comment: Can't you just set a temporary password on your account so you get the login box? Alternatively, you may try to select "Not Listed" when it lists the usernames on the system. That also has the gear icon. I'm not aware of how to do it from the command line, the GUI is the only way I've switched between the two.

Comment: Thanks Bratchley; the still unsolved problem thickens.  Logging in as root, I saw the gear icon when the password box came up, chose KDE (plasma), and then logged in.  The KDE desktop started.  I then logged out and logged back in as Steve, my normal user ID.  Unfortunately, the (old) Gnome desktop persists under my Steve user ID.  I need some way, while logged in as root, to specify that the KDE desktop should apply to all users.  Any ideas?

Comment: You probably had a password on your root account. Try either setting a password on your steve account or instead of selecting "steve" from the users list, select "Not Listed?" which should prompt you for username and password at the same time.

Comment: Re Bratchley's last comment: temporarily setting a password on my steve account works - See Also this website's "Manipulating a (non-root) password in Fedora 22" topic.  At first glance, I underestimated his other suggestion, because I had previously concluded that the Desktop setting is user specific.  I overlooked (and never subsequently explored because my problem was resolved) selecting "Not Listed", and then supplying the username as steve.  Unclear whether that would have offered the (shortcutted) opportunity to specify KDE desktop for Steve.